# How to detect that camera app started from my application has been moved to the backround?

Tags: java, android, qt

In my Qt application for Android, I have to take some actions when the user moves the application to the background. For this task, I use `onPause` method in my main activity and it works like a charm.

However, I also need to know when the camera app that I started from my application has been moved to the background.

**Scenario:**

1. User opens Camera from my application (it is done by `startActivityForResult()` with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent)
2. The user moved the app to the background (by clicking the home button or turn off the screen).

**Issue**: there is no option to detect that camera application has been moved to the background in this case.

I tried several solutions:

1. `onPause` / `onRemove` in mainActivity - obviously it doesn't work because the main activity triggers `onPause` method as soon as I start Camera activity.
2. LifecycleObserver - same as above. It detects pausing when I enter the camera.
3. Reading the state of the application from getRunningAppProcesses() - similar results, the state of the app is the same when it is in the background and when the camera is open.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: It's important to note that when the user opens the camera app from your application, your app *has* moved to the background, so your existing solution is correct (although I would recommend using `onStop` as the signal rather than `onPause`, as the former indicates that your `Activity` is no longer visible).

Comment: Maybe there is indeed a naming issue in my question however, I also need to know when the camera app, that started from my application, is moved to the background. Is it possible?

Comment: Likely not in a reliable way, no. The camera app will be its own process, just running as part of your application's task stack. If you can expand on what you intend to do in response to going to the background, there may be an alternative.

Comment: In response, I have to lock my app (so that the user has to type his password to continue). So I don't think there is an alternative. The camera app is the first step, I have to do the same for importing/exporting files (system's file manager) .. :(